# Does GDB has any keyword for program entry point?

Tags: gdb

I've got a program in c++ with no symbol table and load it in gdb. When I run it, it just exit normally, though I need to trace it. I can't use `trace main` or `trace 0`, so either I find out offset of entry point, or find any keyword for it. Of course, you can say, I should just build it with symbol table, but I'm creating a simple IDE with an option of debugging and it should work as well with files with no symbol table.

So, do anyone know either of this? Thanks for any help. Tried googling, but found nothing useful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

GDB's `info files` will give you an *entry point* which you can then break on.